# Non-linear time-dependent equation

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations

Given 
$$u(x,t)=\cos(t)\cos\left(5 \pi (x-1)/2\right)$$ 
is the actual solution to 
$$u_{t}=\epsilon^{2}u_{xx}+(1-u^{2})u+f(x,t)$$ 
I want to find what f(x,t) should be. I've simplified the results to 
$$f(x,t)={{25}\over{4}} \pi^{2} \epsilon^{2}\cos(t)\sin\left({{5 \pi}\over{2}}x\right)-\sin(t)\sin\left({{5 \pi}\over{2}}x\right) - $$
$$\left(1-\cos^2(t)\sin^2({{5 \pi}\over{2}}x)\right)\cos(t)\sin\left({{5 \pi}\over{2}}x\right)$$ 
but I'm not sure how to simplify it any further. Can anyone help?

Comment: May I ask why do you want to simplify further?

Comment: The expression just seems like I should be able to simplify it more and get something more concise.

Comment: If you want to perform say numerical integration on $f$, this expression is good enough.

Comment: I'm going to be applying a numerical scheme to the equation. I think it's important that $$f(x,t)$$ eliminates the $$(1-u^{2})u$$. Is this right?

Comment: No, your goal is to match this equation with $u$ to construct an example problem. For I am guessing your goal is to test whether the your numerical method works for this nonlinear equation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't completely understand. What do you mean by example problem?

Comment: My point is that the expression of $f$ is good to use, since you prescribed $u$ at the first place.

Comment: Hm, okay. So I'm trying to find the order of accuracy using $f$ and Newton's method for non-linear systems, but I'm not sure how the $f$ I calculated is important. Do you think you could explain?

Comment: Since you have the $f$, now you pretend you don't know $u$ and use Newton's method to solve $u$, see you could get back to the original $u$ with certain order of accuracy.